# Does anyone out there know how to install and manage an SMTP service on a machine that runs Windows VIsta?

Tags: php, email, smtp, windows-vista

I am working on a php program which would allow a user to enter information in a form and then send that information to a particular email address.  I've been told that you need to have something called an SMTP server installed on your computer to make this happen.  However, I have no idea what this is, and when installed, what code to use in order to send emails when someone using the php file enters information in a form and submits it.  Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: I'm not going to be any help with Vista but note this: it is true that to send an email you need access to an smtp server but it does not need to be on the same computer as your code. Given your limited familiarity with smtp I'd be looking for an smtp server you can use instead of one that you personally have to manage.

Answer (score 1):

You need an email server (specifically an SMTP server) in order to send email. If you don't run one yourself, you'll need to send mail through one run by your company or ISP or someone else, the same way you would with any other email client.

Comment: If you try to run an SMTP server from your Vista box you're going to run into nothing but problems across the board with sending.  You're better off leveraging an SMTP server with a good IP address reputation.